# add class img-responsive to all attached post images in wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

i want to add class=img-reponsive & img-shadow to all the attached post thumbnail 
i used following function which works fine but it removes the original classes of thubmails

```
function add_responsive_class($content){

        $content = mb_convert_encoding($content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");
        $document = new DOMDocument();
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $document->loadHTML(utf8_decode($content));

        $imgs = $document->getElementsByTagName('img');
        foreach ($imgs as $img) {           
           $img->setAttribute('class','img-responsive img-shadow');
        }

        $html = $document->saveHTML();
        return $html;   
}
```

But i want to merge my classes not just overwrite them
So i used jquery

```
 jQuery(function() {
jQuery(img).addClass('img-responsive img-shadow ');
});
```

But its giving error jquery not defined

Please help me out

Comment: Did you included the `jQuery` library at first place in your theme's header file, can you be sure that `jQuery` is loaded indeed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
function add_image_responsive_class($content) {
   global $post;
   $pattern ="/<img(.*?)class=\"(.*?)\"(.*?)>/i";
   $replacement = '<img$1class="$2 img-responsive img-shadow"$3>';
   $content = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
   return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'add_image_responsive_class');
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just re-add the original class with your function?

```
function add_responsive_class($content){

        $content = mb_convert_encoding($content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");
        $document = new DOMDocument();
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $document->loadHTML(utf8_decode($content));

        $imgs = $document->getElementsByTagName('img');
        foreach ($imgs as $img) {           
           $img->setAttribute('class','thumbnails img-responsive img-shadow');
        }

        $html = $document->saveHTML();
        return $html;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the DOMDocument method mentioned above, this can cause issues with utf encoding, especially when using special characters through your content editor, for example: £ being convered to ? or other strange characters. You can loop through $img and then use str_replace on $content, but using "terminators" method worked far better for me.